# sqitch : The term 'sqitch' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: dockerfile, environment-variables, sqitch

I've followed the Docker Image [installation instructions](https://sqitch.org/download/docker/) from Sqitch's documentation website, installed the image with:

```
docker pull sqitch/sqitch
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://git.io/JTAi6" -OutFile "sqitch.bat"
```

and added "C:\Users\me\sqitch.bat" to my "Path" environment variable.

I can't, nevertheless, use sqitch as a command in my terminal which forces me to use the path to sqitch.bat instead.

Has anyone experienced similar issues before?